# AngularJS $http.post not getting JSON success response. Instead redirects to URL of the REST endpoint

Tags: django, angularjs, forms

Experiencing an issue with AngularJS $http.post.  After completing the post requests, the form instead of returning the JSON response, it instead redirects to 127.0.0.1:8000/api/forms/create.  The backend response is done with Django Rest Framework.  This is a CORs request.  The angularJS form is hosted on port 9000 making a call to port 8000. When the server is turned off, instead of returning the error alert, it insteads returns a page not found and the url is once again redirected to 127.0.0.1:8000/api/forms/create.
Appreciate any advice.

Below is the controller code for Angular script:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('DemoController', function ($scope, $http, DemoService, Tools) {
  var form_submit = function() {$http.post("127.0.0.1:8000/api/forms/create", {name:$scope.applicant, date:$scope.date, address=$scope.address}).success(function(data){ alert(data); })
  .error(function(error){
    alert('something failed');
  })};
  });
```

Below is the index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    </head>
   <body ng-app="myApp" ng-submit="form_submit()">
    <FORM action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/forms/create/" method="post">
   <INPUT type="text" ng-model="applicant" name="name">
    <INPUT type="text" ng-model="date" name="date"> 
    <INPUT type="text" ng-model="address" name="address">
   <INPUT type="submit" value="Send"> 
    </FORM>
    </body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers/demo.js"></script>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
<FORM ng-submit="form_submit()">
```

instead of

```
<body ng-submit="form_submit()">
```

It should (hopefully) post your $http in the background

Comment: and Srujan Routhu is right: $scope.form_submit= function(){...}

Comment: Thank you.  This was the issue that I was having.  Appreciate all the help everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `/` slash at the end of POST url (see the [`APPEND_SLASH`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#append-slash) setting for reference):

```
$http.post("127.0.0.1:8000/api/forms/create/"...
```

Answer (score 0):

your form_submit variable in the controller is not a scope variable.

Instead of using

```
var form_submit
```

change it to

```
$scope.form_submit
```

I think this will work.